# Why is MediaPlayer's onCompletionListener so unreliable?

Tags: android

I use the MediaOnCompletionListener to release the object, so it's fairly important. However, as you can see from the logcat snippet below, it's not always triggered !!

```
12-30 17:24:41.448: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:24:41.638: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:24:41.818: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:24:49.866: I/myApp(5117): MediaOnCompletionListener triggered
12-30 17:24:50.136: I/myApp(5117): MediaOnCompletionListener triggered
12-30 17:24:50.186: I/myApp(5117): MediaOnCompletionListener triggered
12-30 17:24:55.902: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:24:56.152: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:24:56.322: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:24:56.552: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:25:04.340: I/myApp(5117): MediaOnCompletionListener triggered
12-30 17:25:04.560: I/myApp(5117): MediaOnCompletionListener triggered
12-30 17:25:04.670: I/myApp(5117): MediaOnCompletionListener triggered
12-30 17:25:04.910: I/myApp(5117): MediaOnCompletionListener triggered
12-30 17:25:37.312: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:25:37.592: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:25:37.773: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:25:37.953: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:25:46.161: I/myApp(5117): MediaOnCompletionListener triggered
12-30 17:25:46.351: I/myApp(5117): MediaOnCompletionListener triggered
12-30 17:26:09.423: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:26:35.108: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:26:42.215: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:26:50.594: I/myApp(5117): MediaOnCompletionListener triggered
12-30 17:27:17.059: I/myApp(5117): playSound(/mnt/sdcard/audio/clong-1.mp3 VolumePercent:100)
12-30 17:27:25.448: I/myApp(5117): MediaOnCompletionListener triggered
```

I am testing this on Android 2.3.5
Is this a known issue? Does MediaPlayer's reliability improve on later versions of Android ?

Comment: Are you sure that your `OnCompletionListener` is actually registered to the `MediaPlayer` in the cases where no log is printed? It might be worth attaching a debugger to confirm the relevant field is non-null at runtime. Alternatively, IIRC, if you set `setLooping(true)` at some point during playback, it will not use the callback after each 'loop' (unless you set it back to `false` before completion).

Comment: Are you sure that the thread that started the MediaPlayer is still alive when OnCompleition fires?   
Check this question it might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875146/ensure-mediaplayer-oncompletionlistener-is-called-and-the-thread-is-not-dead/14061862#14061862

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe
[Garbage Collection causes : MediaPlayer finalized without being released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023037/garbage-collection-causes-mediaplayer-finalized-without-being-released)
will give a clue.

The folks discovered that under some circumstances the player gets garbage-collected before it is released. Maybe, onCompletionListener is not called for already garbage-collected players.