# Android SoundPool end event listener?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

I've started messing about with Android recently. I'm trying to kick something off once a sound has finished and return to the previous activity.

```
spool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        int soundID = spool.load(this, card.getSound(), 1);
        spool.play(soundID, 500, 500, 1, 0, 1f);
```

I can't see anything about getting the sound duration or any sort of sound end event. I know SoundPool can be a pain so I'm willing to ditch it.

How can I do something after a sound has ended? Can I do this with SoundPool or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks. I'm pretty new to Android and Java so open to all suggestions.

Comment: Having gone down this path myself in the past, I'd go with Fabian and switch to MediaPlayer. SoundPool doesn't have an event for this, plus if the length of your sound samples creeps up beyond a few seconds, you'll probably run into the problem where they just cut off, as SoundPool has quite small fixed buffer sizes for sounds (not well documented, from what I remember.) MediaPlayer has a completion listener and can play arbitrary-length samples. Think of SoundPool as useful for short, "fire and forget" sound effects in games, MediaPlayer for everything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the multi-stream handling functionality of `SoundPool` isn't necessary, you can use [`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), which does have the callbacks you're asking about.

A rough example:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Activity.this, soundId);
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // do something
    }
});
mp.start();
```

Just make sure that you hang onto the MediaPlayer reference somewhere so that it [doesn't get GC'd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023037/garbage-collection-causes-mediaplayer-finalized-without-being-released) before your OnCompletionListener fires :)

Comment: I'll check it out. I suspected SoundPool was a lost cause but it did the job.

Comment: I *think* SoundPool is more targeted at game-like situations, where you'd often need to play multiple sounds in response to various events, without necessarily caring about when they finish.