# How sound will play in background if player is closed?

Tags: android

I have developed a audio player in android with the help of Google and its working fine but i got one problem when i close player song stop playing. I want song should play unlit user manually stop song. So anybody have any suggestion how i can do that.

Thanks

Comment: Service will make the trick here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically like all said we need to use service to do this task as activity looses its content. so have a look at bellow example.

link http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-i

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) should get you started, also see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875146/ensure-mediaplayer-oncompletionlistener-is-called-and-the-thread-is-not-dead/14061862#14061862) for a complete example